# Apache Cordova - Failed to generate v1 signature

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, phonegap

```
Cordova 8.1.1 (cordova-lib@8.1.0)
Android 7.1.1
OSX 10.13.6
```

The following Cordova release build command errors out. What are we doing wrong?

```
$ cordova build --release android

BUILD FAILED in 5s
46 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 44 up-to-date
/Users/xxx/QS/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> Failed to generate v1 signature
```

build.json

```
  {
    "android": {
      "release": {
        "keystore": "/Users/xxx/QS/platforms/android/appreleasedemo.keystore",
        "storePassword": "password",
        "alias": "appreleasedemoalias",
        "password" : "password"
      }
    }
  }
```

The keystore is present:

```
$ keytool -keystore /Users/xxx/QS/platforms/android/appreleasedemo.keystore -list

Keystore type: jks
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

appreleasedemoalias, Oct 1, 2018, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): FC:63:EC:88:0A:A2:ED:B4:7A:34:C1:76:F9:98:F5:E0:8D:85:7A:4F
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio: Error:org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to generate v1 signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248406/android-studio-errororg-gradle-tooling-buildexception-failed-to-generate-v1-s)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found I was able to fix this issue by using the following command line to build a new key file, as desribed at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html:

`keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias my-alias`

Specifically, I believe the problem is that the default has changed from RSA to DSA at some point, and the tools don't work correctly with large DSA keys.