# Google Sign in failing due to SharedElementCallback

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, google-signin

I have used pretty much the boilerplate from firebase and google sign on documentation. I get the dialog for choosing the account to log in from, and then it fails. I have updated my google play services. And also regenerated my sha1 keys. One thing that I have noticed is that android studio keeps giving me back the old key when executing the signingreport task, tho I have generated keys twice after that, and also updated on the firebase console.

[Gist of the main activity on github](https://gist.github.com/opheliagame/495375568db9f468139a594ac923807a)

```
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat$SharedElementCallback23Impl', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.setEnterSharedElementCallback
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat$SharedElementCallback21Impl', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.setEnterSharedElementCallback
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat$SharedElementCallback23Impl', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.setExitSharedElementCallback
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat$SharedElementCallback21Impl', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.setExitSharedElementCallback
```

Comment: Have you added/imported the `SharedElementCallback23Impl` library/class?

Comment: I have not used the class explicitly in the code. I think some function or class that I have used calls it in turn, so I shouldn't have to import it right?

Comment: Give it a try, do you have the same behaviour?

Comment: Yes, even after explicitly importing it, it crashes in the same way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, because android studio was showing me the wrong, originally generated key when running the `signingreport` task from `gradle`, I tried generating new keys but that wasn't working. 
And then I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965058/where-is-debug-keystore-in-android-studio) which explained how to find the debug keystore in android studio and set it up. My android studio was taking its keys from the `.android` directory in my home directory while I was generating keys in a different directory. After configuring the keys through this, I also got an error saying the key strength was very less, but that was easy to [solve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248406/android-studio-errororg-gradle-tooling-buildexception-failed-to-generate-v1-s)(just add the `-keyalg RSA` argument while generating keys.

And then when I launched the app it said that due to CA certificates being no longer valid I should uninstall and install again. And voila, it worked.