# How can I use the current `*.keystore` to build successfully or migrate to new key but play store will also accept it?

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, keystore

I'm upgrading an android app to Target API level 30 (Android 11) [because of it's required](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk) as of Nov 2021.

How can I use the current signing key `*.keystore` and build it without errors or migrate to new signing key but play store will also accept it?

If I use current `*.keystore` to sign my app, I got errors in `Android Studio 4.2`

```
Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.FinalizeBundleTask$BundleToolRunnable
   > Failed to generate v1 signature

and

The security strength of SHA-1 digest algorithm is not sufficient for this key size
```

If I [generate a new key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48266417/6414615) by keytool , it works for building, but got errors on google play store after uploaded the `aab`.

errors from play store

```
Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App 
Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again. Your app bundle is expected to be signed with the certificate with fingerprint:
```

more info

`$ keytool -list -v -keystore ./{yourkeystore}.keystore -alias xxxxxx -storepass xxxxxx -keypass xxxxxx`

It shows `Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit DSA key (3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by customer support, they allow to use the new key.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/gethelp